# pyttsx3 hangs up on converting big files to mp3

Tags: python, text-to-speech, pyttsx, pyttsx3

## code:

```
import os
import glob
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()

file_pattern = '*.txt'
file_name_list = []

if '*' in file_pattern:
    file_name_list.extend(glob.glob(file_pattern))

# speech rate
engine.setProperty('rate', 600)
rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
# speech volume
volume = engine.getProperty('volume')
engine.setProperty('volume',1.0)
# speech voice
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

engine.runAndWait() # engine start

for target in file_name_list:
    string_to_parse = ''
    with open(target,'r',encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as text_file:
        for i in text_file.readlines():
            string_to_parse = string_to_parse + i
            mp3_filename = target.replace('.txt','.mp3')
            fullPath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), mp3_filename)
            engine.save_to_file(string_to_parse, fullPath)
            engine.runAndWait()
```

## problem:

This code can write a folder full of small files containing one string to mp3, but if I try to convert multiple books it hangs up for eternity. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing a single line you should exit the for loop with the complete sentence in the variable string_to_parse and then you can save it to a mp3

```
import os
import glob
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()

file_pattern = '*.txt'
file_name_list = []

if '*' in file_pattern:
    file_name_list.extend(glob.glob(file_pattern))

# speech rate
engine.setProperty('rate', 600)
rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
# speech volume
volume = engine.getProperty('volume')
engine.setProperty('volume',1.0)
# speech voice
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

engine.runAndWait() # engine start

for target in file_name_list:
    string_to_parse = ''
    with open(target,'r',encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as text_file:
        for i in text_file.readlines():
            string_to_parse = string_to_parse + i
        mp3_filename = target.replace('.txt','.mp3')
        fullPath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), mp3_filename)
        engine.save_to_file(string_to_parse, fullPath)
        engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: My goal here is to write an entire book's worth of text to an mp3, so I'm handling multiple sentences, returns, etc.

Comment: The above code does that it writes entire books worth of text to string_to_parse variable and the writes string_to_parse to mp3 file

Comment: That did work. Although it appears mp3 is more corrupt than wav. 
Thank you.